# ¿Còmo pasar datos de json a grafica de AMchar con react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, bootstrap

¡Hola, que tal! Soy nuevo en react y me descarge algunas graficas de AMCHART
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-chart-with-axis-break/
Estoy aprendiendo a pasar datos de un Json a una tabla o a una grafica.

Les dejo el codigo de mi tabla que estoy traajando y el json que quiero pasar, le falta la ultima parte a este, pero no afecta.

Importe mis datos llamados prueba.json pero después de ese paso, no sé como exactamente indicarle a la tabla que use mis datos. :c Ayuda.

Muchisimas gracias! Espero poder ver como pasar los datos a esta grafica. :)

```js
[
    {
        "Nombre del Archivo": "hola.pdf",
        "Dimensiones pixeles": 200,
        "Evaluación de acuerdo": "Pasa",
        "Calidad según modelo": "Buena"
    },
    {
        "Nombre del Archivo": "hola.pdf",
        "Dimensiones pixeles": 300,
        "Evaluación de acuerdo": "No pasa",
        "Calidad según modelo": "Buena"
    },
    {
        "Nombre del Archivo": "hola.pdf",
        "Dimensiones pixeles": 400,
        "Evaluación de acuerdo": "Pasa",
        "Calidad según modelo": "Buena"
    },
    {
        "Nombre del Archivo": "hola.pdf",
        "Dimensiones pixeles": 400,
        "Evaluación de acuerdo": "Pasa",
        "Calidad según modelo": "Buena"
    }
]
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import prueba from '../prueba.json';


function Tabla() {
    return (
        <>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col style={{ maxHeight: '250px', overflow: 'auto' }}>
                        <Table striped bordered hover>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Nombre del Archivo</th>
                                    <th>Dimensiones pixeles por pulgada</th>
                                    <th>Evaluación de acuerdo a la NOM Paso o No Pasa según NOM</th>
                                    <th>Calidad según modelo</th>
                                    <th>Número de páginas analizadas</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Grupo.pdf</b></td>
                                    <td><b>200x200</b></td>
                                    <td><b>Pasa</b></td>
                                    <td><b>Buena</b></td>
                                    <td><b>62</b></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Grupo.pdf</b></td>
                                    <td><b>200x200</b></td>
                                    <td><b>Pasa</b></td>
                                    <td><b>Buena</b></td>
                                    <td><b>62</b></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Grupo.pdf</b></td>
                                    <td><b>200x200</b></td>
                                    <td><b>Pasa</b></td>
                                    <td><b>Buena</b></td>
                                    <td><b>62</b></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </Table>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
}




export default Tabla;
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: No hay error, el problema es que no sé como pasar los datos del json a la tabla. Se supone que se usa una función llamada .map o algo así.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al importar el archivo JSON en automático ya podrás ingresar a las propiedades del objecto, en este caso tu archivo JSON contiene un arreglo de objetos, para iterar en ese arreglo puedes usar la función map, esta función lo que hace es iterar sobre un arreglo y te regresa un nuevo arreglo del mismo tamaño en longitud, pero te da la posibilidad de editar los valores en cada index.
El ejemplo en código seria el siguiente:

```
  import React, { Fragment } from "react";
  import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
  import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
  import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
  import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
  import prueba from "../prueba.json";

  function Tabla() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col style={{ maxHeight: "250px", overflow: "auto" }}>
              <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Nombre del Archivo</th>
                    <th>Dimensiones pixeles por pulgada</th>
                    <th>
                      Evaluación de acuerdo a la NOM Paso o No Pasa según NOM
                    </th>
                    <th>Calidad según modelo</th>
                    <th>Número de páginas analizadas</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {(prueba || []).map((item) => (
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <b>{item["Nombre del Archivo"] || ""}</b>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <b>{item["Dimensiones pixeles"] || ""}</b>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <b>{item["Evaluación de acuerdo"] || ""}</b>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <b>{item["Calidad según modelo"] || ""}</b>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <b>{62}</b>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </Table>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Me sirvio! :D Buen día caballero! :)